# Como criar um vetor através da união entre outros 2

Tags: c, array, parâmetros, declaração-de-variável

Estou fazendo um exercício com vetores onde preciso ler dois vetores de 5 posições cada, e após isso, concatenar esses dois em um 3 de 10 posições.

Meu programa está imprimindo corretamente o primeiro vetor, mas no segundo ele imprime 4, 5, 5, 2686760, 1987092020 (acho que são endereços).

Seguem as funções:

```
int criaVetor3(int v[], int v1[]){

int v3[10];

for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
    v3[i] = v[i];
}

for(i=4; i<=9; i++){ // Começa no 5 elemento do vetor e vai até o 10
    v3[i] = v1[i-5];
}
}

int mostraVetor3(int v[], int v1[]){

int v3[10];

for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
    printf("O numero posicao [%d] e %d\n", i, v[i]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código nem compila. Resolvendo estes problemas deu tudo certo, eu só estilizei melhor.

Faltava declaração de variável e faltava retornar ou passar um vetor de cobertura, o que eu preferi fazer para não envolver alocação dinâmica.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void criaVetor(int v[], int v1[], int v2[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v[i] = v1[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) v[i + 5] = v2[i];
}

void mostraVetor(int v[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("O numero posicao [%d] e %d\n", i, v[i]);
}

int main(void) {
    int v[10];
    int v1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int v2[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    criaVetor(v, v1, v2);
    mostraVetor(v);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/krUnlq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ivkmyuni-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Join.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado, eu não coloquei o código inteiro porque tem mais algumas funções e um menu, coloquei só as funções da parte que eu estava tendo dificuldade mas enfim, agradeço muito pela ajuda!

Answer (score -2):

Bom,

O erro aconteceu comigo também e eu descobri.

Exemplo: Vetor 1 = 1, 2, 3 e Vetor 2 = 9, 8, 7

O Vetor 3 junta o primeiro e o segundo.

Veja, quando você coloca a primeiro for, o índice do vetor 3 e do vetor 1 são iguais e colocam as informações corretamente.

Mas quando você tenta colocar o segundo vetor, no vetor 3 dá esse erro.

```
 Vetor 1 = 1, 2, 3
```

Posição de i = 0, 1, 2

```
 Vetor 2 = 9, 8, 7
```

Posição de i = 0, 1, 2

```
 Vetor 3 = 1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7
```

Posição de i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Para i=0; enquanto for menor 3; i++;

V3[i] = V1[i];

Para o próximo raciocínio, vamos usar uma variável auxiliar, porque a posição do vetor 2 tem que ser percorrida do início em 0 e não igual ao i que começa em 3.

aux=0;

Para i=3; enquanto for menor que 6; i++, aux++;

V3[i] = V2[aux];

Assim vai.

Tenta entender e vê se funciona.  Funcionou para mim...